# Github compare shows differences that aren't there?

Tags: github, version-control

I'm comparing two branches on github. In "files changed", there are changes being displayed for files that are identical in both branches.

Is this because of the commit history of one/both of the branches or something? Is there some way just to compare the CURRENT state of the branches and ignore the commit history (if that is the problem)

Comment: Do you see anything when you look at the diff of the files? There might be differences that affect e.g. just whitespace.

Comment: No, those files don't appear there. I think I've figured out why they show up on github though - github does a "..." comparison which means it doesn't compare the current state of the branches, but rather the current state of one branch to the most recent commit that they both have (e.g. the commit where one branch was created off the other). I have no clue why this is the default behavior though